# XmlDocument get sub items

Tags: c#, parsing, xmldocument

i'm trying to get the sub item from this XML document:

XML CODE HERE :

```
<RUNNABLES>
  <RUNNABLE-ENTITY UUID="1661dcae-c4b9-4f47-8b68-cb99c677bdd6">
    <SHORT-NAME>RCtApElg_mlm</SHORT-NAME>
      <DESC>
    <L-2 L="FOR-ALL">The unique runnable entity of the Main Lights SW Component</L-2>
  </DESC>
</RUNNABLES>
```

So far, this is what i made:

C# code here

```
XmlDocument xmlReader = new XmlDocument();
xmlReader.PreserveWhitespace = false;
xmlReader.Load(strfilename);

XmlNodeList elemList = xmlReader.SelectNodes("/RUNNABLES/RUNNABLE-ENTITY/SHORT-NAME");
```

How I can specify to read SHORT-NAME tag and get "RCtApElg_mlm" value as result?

Comment: How about using `SelectSingleNode` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you fix the sample xml (it misses the closure tag for RUNNABLE-ENTITY), this should work:

```
XmlDocument xmlReader = new XmlDocument();
xmlReader.PreserveWhitespace = false;
xmlReader.Load(strfilename);

XmlNodeList elemList = xmlReader.SelectNodes("//RUNNABLES/RUNNABLE-ENTITY/SHORT-NAME");
string value = elemList.Item(0).InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:
`.Value`

`XmlNodeList elemList = xmlReader.SelectNodes("/RUNNABLES/RUNNABLE-ENTITY/SHORT-NAME").Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I did:

```
                    XmlNode node = xmlReader.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
                    XmlNodeList lstPackage = node.ChildNodes;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(lstPackage[i].Name.ToString());
                        if (lstPackage[i].Name == "AR-PACKAGE")
                        {
                            aux++;
                        }
                        if(aux==2)
                        {
                            aux = 0;
                            XmlNodeList lstShortname = lstPackage[i].FirstChild.ChildNodes;
                            // Display the value of its first child node
                            for (int j = 0; j < lstShortname.Count; j++)
                                MessageBox.Show(lstShortname[j].InnerText);
                        }
                    }
```

Dont know if its the best option, but I get as result.

Thanks!